# Resources for learning Russian

Tags: resources

Using the same structure in the [Chinese Resources question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1120/43), this is a specifically created Community Wiki which gathers resources for learning Russian and [it has been approved by the Community itself](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/71).

It should be clear that **the resources are not written by one user or only by the mods, but by whoever wants to contribute.**

Just write in the appropriate answer/section. If you have concerns, questions, [ask a question in our Meta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), so we don't clutter the comments, but you can link your meta question from the comments.

Questions regarding such resources **are not allowed anymore**, and they will closed as a duplicate of this question, except for very specific and on topic requests (ask on Meta if you're unsure about your question). Follow the instructions made in the question about how to post, what can be posted, etc.

#### Organization

- Answers have a type of resource **each**.
- If possible, state whether the material is directed towards a **beginner**, **intermediate** or an **advanced** audience.
- **Do not** include links that lead to illegal content or sites that host such content. If you see any, please **flag for moderator attention** and choose "other" so you can point us to the content. We'll delete it as soon as we see the flag.
- [Both free and commercial resources are allowed](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/203/71), but make sure to include a note if they are. Remember the [rules about self-promotion](https://russian.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). Include also if registration is required.
- Include links to the sites only, *don't post images*, they would take too much space.
- Add the resources in alphabetical order so they're easier to find. :)

*Note: new rules could be added in the future.*

#### Alphabetical Index

- [Add-ons (browser)](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/834/71): These are plugins that you install on your browser and that help you in different ways, such as providing word meanings, etc.
- [Audiobooks](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/835/71): Audio files where you hear a voice reading the book you've chosen.
- [Books](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/836/71): Books from Russian authors or translations.
- [Dictionaries](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/837/71): Stand-alone or dictionary files for you to use on your computer.
- [Newspapers](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/838/71): Famous or not services that provide news for Russia and the rest of the world... in Russian.
- [Online courses](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/839/71): Free or paid services online that teach you the language through lessons.
- [Podcasts](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/840/71): Audio files that feature people speaking about the language or giving tips/lessons to learners.
- [Television](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/841/71): TV channels, shows in Russian.
- [Textbooks](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/842/71): Grammar books that teach you the grammar of the language with theory and exercises.
- [Websites](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/843/71): Sites that give help for learning Russian. They give material, tips, hints, and various help for self-learners or regular students.

Comment: Such a great question and greater answers, thank you.

Comment: What is the proper place to disclose one's affiliation with a resource one adds?

Comment: At an advanced level you can use yandex.ru which is leading russian search engine to find topics of interest, russian news etc.

Answer (score 25):

### Websites

- [BBC Russian Language Service](http://www.bbc.co.uk/russian/)
- [Convertcyrillic.com](http://www.convertcyrillic.com/linkerizer.aspx), a tool for students to easily look up multiple Russian words.
- [Langust](http://www.langust.ru/rus_gram/rus_gram.shtml) - short Russian grammar
- [lib.ru](http://lib.ru/), Библиотека Максима Мошкова, the largest Russian library in the Internet history.
- [Learn to speak Russian](http://russian-1000words.pw) - Russian learning site that provides a lot of helpful lessons and other information, including original course from beginning to confident level, and original books. The blog of Russian-1000words.pw contains a lot of different information on Russian language.
- [learnrussianweb.com](http://www.learnrussianweb.com/), a site for learning Russian
- [learnrussian.rt.com](http://learnrussian.rt.com), Russian lessons. Online and free.  See also  - [masterrussian.com](http://masterrussian.com/), Russian lessons, vocabulary, test, forum
  [community provided answer keys](https://www.explaura.net/learnrussian-rt-com))
- [100 top resources to learn Russian](http://russian.lingualift.com/blog/best-russian-learning-resources/) - a list of online and print resources, categorized by type and level
- [Памятка корректору](http://u3poccuu.livejournal.com/7681.html) - quick reference on most common Russian grammatical, syntax and spelling mistakes
- [Ruskie.info] [7](http://ruskie.info) - Russian lessons built around Russian news and realities.
- [Ruslang.ru](http://www.ruslang.ru/)
- [ruspeach.com] [1](http://www.ruspeach.com/) - Ruspeach is an online Russian Language learning resource.
- [Russian For Everyone](http://www.russianforeveryone.com/) - Russian language self study guide for beginners
- [Russian Language History](http://www.kvatross.ru/index.php)
- [Russian Language List](https://russian-langauge-list.nuhub.net) - Directory of free resources including lessons, dictionaries, and films
- [Russian Lessons](http://www.russianlessons.net) - Grammar, vocabulary lists and texts (in Russian and English side-by-side). Tests are read out loud by native speakers.
- [Russian Morpheem](http://russian.morpheem.com) – a searchable, hypertext-style index of all grammar and vocabulary up to intermediate level. Free.
- [Russian National Corpus search](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/en/search-main.html) - allows to search for examples of a word usage and the word collocations.
- [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru/) - website dedicated to the most problematic rule.
- [udarenie.info](http://www.udarenie.info) - database of words with stresses marked + linguistic game to remember correct stresses; search function is based on gramota.ru.
- [Записки отважного бойца языкового фронта](https://lingvanotes.blogspot.com/) - quick reference on Russian grammar, lexis, spelling
- [Национальный корпус русского языка](https://ruscorpora.ru/) - A curated and searchable body of texts in Russian. Useful for checking context, usus and connotation of a given word or phrase. For advanced level learners.
- [Poetry Reader for Russian Learners](http://russianpoetry.yale.edu/) - A companion website for the book by the same name from Julia Titus. It contains poems with stress marks and translation for most obscure words. It will be useful for those who study by learning poems by heart. (From intermediate to advanced level.)

Comment: Duolingo is really good as well. It's Babel but free and less content. Amazing UX imo.

Answer (score 13):

### Online courses

- [Babbel](http://www.babbel.com) - beautiful resource for language learning. They've just added new Russian courses.
- [Busuu](http://busuu.com/) — online language learning site. Basic profile is free.
- [Duolingo](https://en.duolingo.com/course/ru/en/Learn-Russian-Online) - free language courses delivered via web-based and mobile applications.
- [Edufire/languages/Russian](http://edufire.com/subjects/russian) — a site where you can try and find a teacher of Russian with whom you later connect via edufire web-site or Skype. (For-pay.)
- [Memrise](http://www.memrise.com/courses/english/russian/) — a spaced repetition learning website. It has several Russian courses. It is mainly just memorizing vocabulary.
- [RussianForFree.com](http://www.russianforfree.com/) — free lessons from basic level to advanced, texts with audio, grammar, activities, and much more. No Sign-up required either.
- [Russian LinguaLift](http://russian.lingualift.com/) — online Russian textbook, spaced repetition tools and educational games. (For-pay.)
- [Russian World](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF2F566484C119BF4) — video lectures of 2 years of Russian language courses from [Dallas ISD](http://www.dallasisd.org/Page/2144).
- [Easy Russian](https://www.youtube.com/user/vanilla167333) - regularly updated YouTube channel. Conversational Russian with Russian and English subtitles. (! Channel closed)
- [Fluent in Russian](http://speakfluentrussian.com) - free audio lessons in the form of questions and answers for developing speaking and listening skills, as well as grammar and vocabulary.
- [Russian For Everyone](http://russianforeveryone.com/) - Russian language self study guide for beginners.
- [ReadyRussian.org](https://www.readyrussian.org/) - 16-week course for classroom use, includes exercises, quizzes
- [О русском по-русски](https://www.youtube.com/c/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8) - Russian courses in Russian for Russian-(little bit)speaking learners. Courses are in Russian but are accessible for intermediate.

Comment: Somehow Fluent in Russian is no longer up.

Answer (score 12):

### Dictionaries

- [ABBYY Lingvo.ru](http://lingvopro.abbyyonline.com/ru), multilingual dictionary.
- [Academic](http://dic.academic.ru/), an extensive collection of Russian dictionaries
- [Gramota](http://gramota.ru/), grammar reference and more
- [lurkmore.to](http://lurkmore.to), russian lurkmore: an on-line encyclopedia of interesting facts, focused on memes (stable ideas and expressions) of runet.
- [Multitran](http://www.multitran.ru/), great translations for English-Russian, German-Russian, and includes grammatical tables, but doesn't mark stress
- [ru.wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/), online dictionary and grammatical tables
- [Пиздец!](http://www.russki-mat.net/e/Russian.php) - Russian-English slang dictionary | Словарь русского мата и неформального языка
- [Open Russian](https://en.openrussian.org) - English-Russian and German-Russian dictionary with examples, declension and stressmarks.

Answer (score 7):

### Television

- [LiveTV](http://livetv.ru/), online streaming of sporting events
- [1tv.ru](http://1tv.ru) News in Russian, the newsreaders speak very good Russian.

Comment: Official Mosfilm movies collection [with English subtitles](http://cinema.mosfilm.ru/films/comp/Podborki/Filmy-s-subtitrami/) (mostly Soviet ones).

Comment: @Artemix 404 страница не найдена

Comment: https://youtu.be/Tg1CiIRT418 - "6 frames", etc, the comedian tv-show.

Answer (score 7):

### Articles about writing texts in Russian

[Collection of articles](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Al3ROaF1pTROdEFjc1REcDdxTkE0T0g2eHJsNDQ2NFE#gid=0) by art-director A. Lebedev, editor M. Ilyahov and other respectable people in web-development.

Answer (score 5):

### Books

- Russian for Mathematicians, Edited by Doctor of Sciences A. Petukhov, Publishing House of Moscow Center, for Continous Mathematical Education, MOSCOW, 2004

Answer (score 4):

### Newspapers

- [Викиновости](http://ru.wikinews.org), online free news anyone can edit - Russian section of the site
- [Газета.ру](http://www.gazeta.ru/), online Russian newspaper
- [Известия.ру](http://izvestia.ru/), Russian newspaper
- [Лента.ру](http://www.lenta.ru/), online Russian newspaper
- [Правда.ру](http://www.pravda.ru/), Russian newspaper.

Answer (score 3):

### Add-ons

- [Language Immersion for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/language-immersion-for-ch/bedbecnakfcpmkpddjfnfihogkaggkhl): Switches certain words and phrases on the web pages from English into Russian (or another selected language)
- [RussianGram](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/russiangram/bidcnmfhffpamjhgkemdmjdmnchjnmdf) (for Chrome): Adds stress marks to Russian websites.

Comment: That page is down (2020-07-11)

Comment: You can copy and paste any text in RussianGram. The add-on which adds stress marks to all Russian websites is only for Chrome, but the site is helpful anyway, regardless of your browser.

Comment: The Language Immersion for Chrome add-on does not seem to exist anymore, or at least the link to it has changed.

Answer (score 3):

### Podcasts

- [KG-Portal](https://kg-portal.ru/transcripts/), 196 episodes of two podcasts notable for having transcripts.
- [PodFM](http://podfm.ru), Podcast directory for Russian language podcasts
- [Russian Podcast](http://russianpodcast.eu/podcasts.html), Simple audio for those who know basic grammar and want to improve their Russian
- [Taste of Russian](http://www.tasteofrussian.com/) Resource for upper-intermediate or advanced learners of Russian. Downloadable Russian mp3 podcast feed with scripts submitted. As far as basic practical use is concerned, registration is not required.

Answer (score 2):

### Audiobooks

- [ruspeach.com](http://www.ruspeach.com/handbook/podcasts/) - vocalized works of great Russian classics and modern authors. Ruspeach website is translated in 9 languages and it is developing and improving everyday.

Answer (score 2):

### Textbooks

- German: MOCT - Modernes Russisch - Aktualisierte Ausgabe: Modernes Russisch. Moct 1. Arbeitsbuch mit 2 Audio-CDs: Niveau A1-A2. ISBN: 978-3125275669
- Dutch: J.L.I. Fennell, [Russisch voor Zelfstudie](https://www.prisma.nl/producten/russisch-voor-zelfstudie-9789000353286), ISBN: 9789000353286
- [The online library of the Russian as Foreign Language Faculty site of the Lomonosov Moscow State University](http://www.mgu-russian.com/elibrary/ru/online:4). You can find references to many good textbooks there. However, the access is only open to those who visit their courses.
- [Sputnik: An Introductory Russian Language Course](http://www.sputniktextbook.org).  Designed to develop basic reading, writing, listening and communication skills. A free complementary website comes with a lot of sounds and quizzes.
- [***Troika: A Communicative Approach to Russian Language, Life, and Culture***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Troika/AAJZPRNYU_MC?hl=en&gbpv=0)
  Textbook assigned to first year students of Russian at the [**University of Washington**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Washington) (in 2014, anyway).  Purchase of the book also includes access to a companion website which has textbook audio, interactive grammar exercises, self-tests, typing tutor exercises, and vocabulary flashcards.  An [**Activities Manual**](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Troika_Activities_Manual/bMnj8iRN9IEC?hl=en&gbpv=0) may be purchased separately.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose everything below is for "intermediate" and "advanced" levels.

---

Various WEBSITES:

https://wordassociations.net/ru/ - An associative dictionary for enriching artistic language;

http://jeck.ru/tools/SynonymsDictionary/ - Dictionary of synonyms

https://kartaslov.ru/ - Map of words and expressions of the Russian language.

https://glvrd.ru.  Glavred Ilyakhova - Cleans out "rubbish" and bureaucratese in the text.  You need to use it without fanaticism, since it is adjusted to informational-commercial texts.  Suitable for those who unconsciously overload sentences and do not see why this is bad.  The service highlights unwanted words and gives a capacious, slightly sarcastic explanation on the right.

[http://www.онлайн-исправление.рф/](http://www.xn----7sbbiparddsgqdgdxrq.xn--p1ai/) Program for automatic correction of typos and mistakes;

https://www.languagetool.org/ru Grammar and style corrector;

http://orthographia.ru/ Russian spelling and punctuation rules.
Complete academic reference book edited by V.V.Lopatin;

http://old-rozental.ru/ D.E. Rosenthal: Reference book on the Russian language - spelling and punctuation;

http://old-punctum.ru/ Punctuation reference book.

---

on-line libraries:

http://www.lib.ru/

http://loveread.ec/

http://www.e-reading-lib.com/

http://militera.lib.ru/

https://royallib.com/

http://flibusta.is/

http://www.rusf.ru/

https://www.twirpx.com/

https://www.litres.ru/

http://www.vostlit.info/ - Library of historical texts.

---

https://www.m-translate.ru/ is a good online auto-translator.

---

On-line QUIZ game in Russian https://russia.triviador.net/

---

Etymology:

http://www.proto-indo-european.ru/pie-roots-all.htm - list of Indo-European wordroots in Russian(etc).

https://www.etymonline.com/ - English (this is related) etymology.

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary - Wiktionary with etymology.

Answer (score 0):

ONLINE COURSES

["Time to speak Russian"](https://www.irlc.msu.ru/irlc_projects/speak-russian/time_new/eng/course/)
A very useful resource to learn Russian for beginners. 10 lessons take you from scratch to an intermediary level with videos.

Other videos of a more advanced level, made by the same center, can be found on their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/TimetoSpeakRussian/videos).

[https://www2.gwu.edu/~slavic/golosa/audio/audio1-4e.htm](https://www2.gwu.edu/%7Eslavic/golosa/audio/audio1-4e.htm)

[https://www2.gwu.edu/~slavic/golosa/audio/audio2-4e.htm](https://www2.gwu.edu/%7Eslavic/golosa/audio/audio2-4e.htm)
Another website to learn Russian (for intermediate/advandced level). The first link is for beginners, the second one for intermediate level. Though the user interface is not very clear, it contains a lot of dialogues and "oral drills" to get some training (by repeating) by yourself.

https://learnrussian.rt.com/lessons/ is the website of Russia Today devoted to Russian language.

https://ccle.ucla.edu/course/view/russian_RLWS?section=1 is the public display of the course site devoted to Russian from the UCLA.

USEFUL WEBSITE/ADD-ON
http://russiangram.com/ automatically adds (right) stress marks.

MOVIES IN RUSSIAN WITH ENGLISH SUBTITLES
[Mosfilm](https://cinema.mosfilm.ru/) provides free access to hundreds of Russian and Soviet movies, with English or Russian subtitles.

RUSSIAN DICTIONARY
For advanced users, [Словарь русского языка в 4х томах (1999)](http://feb-web.ru/feb/mas/mas-abc/default.asp) is a very exhaustive dictionary of Russian language, with this online version.

TESTS AND ONLINE COURSES
The [Pushkin Institute](https://pushkininstitute.ru/?locale=en) provides a lot of resources of students and teachers of Russian, as well as linguistic tests.