# Popular textbook for learning Russian?

Tags: обучение

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)

I am anxious to learn Russian. I am curious if is there is a popular textbook for student who are learning introduction to Russian ? What is the most popular method to learn it ? I am starting to learn a little bit about their Alphabet and their meaning. I took geography of the former Soviet Union when I was in college and learn about their geography relationship to the former country that was break up from the USSR.

Please advice me on which textbook is good to have and to learn ?

Comment: Hello Probert. Sorry but resource questions are not on topic anymore unless they're very specific. While there are not textbooks in the duplicate I gave, there are some resources. For now it's not that full, but with time, it's going to have more resources in it. :) If you have any concerns, feel free to comment here or open a Meta question (if you have more to say). Hope you stick around!

Comment: I know only a textbook for German students (see textbook section in Resources), it's what my GF uses to teach here in Germany. However, you can always take a look at Amazon for "Russian textbook" or similar in your language.

Comment: I've added a link to a list of references to "Resources for learning Russian", check it out.