# Need help with the meaning of a word: "убийства"

Tags: перевод

I started studying russian this year, I am able to read russian already but still have next to no vocabulary.

Either way, the other day I was playing Borderlands 2, and when I zoomed in with a sniper, I noticed there was a russian word on the scope, which was something like: убийства

I'm sure about the "убий" part, while the rest not entirely, but somthing like that, which is "ства"... there is a chance that there was a "ц" on the middle though...

I'm sorry if it is a vague question, but I tried searching for it but haven't found anything that I could use.

Comment: http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE, there you can see that your word is the plural form of `убийство`

Comment: As a note for the next time, check out our [Resources post](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian), it contains an online dictionary that finds different morphological forms of the same word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a plural form of the noun ¨убийство¨ which means "a murder".

Comment: Thanks a lot, and it does make a lot of sense for where I found it

Answer (score 0):

It is the plural of [*убийство*](http://enru.dict.cc/?s=%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) meaning *murder*.