# How can I begin to learn the Russian language?

Tags: значения, обучение

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)

I am interested in learning the Russian language. Where I live, there isn't any institution that teaches the Russian language (that's a big  problem). How can I start and have correct pronunciation?

Comment: Take a look at http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian

Comment: If you are interested particularly in pronunciation, some live conversation would be definitely useful. If paid skype lessons will work in your part of the world, try them (see [Resources for learning Russian](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian), otherwise try to repost the same question to [facebook group Russian Language](https://www.facebook.com/groups/201667639844312/). Maybe you will find a conversation partner close to your place.