# Homographs that differ only with respect to a stress

Tags: ударение, омографы

A friend of mine is working on a software that places stress in Russian words. In the process, he got himself wondering about words that differ only with respect to stress, like “за́мок” and “замо́к”.

So far, we have only found pairs of words with same written form and different accentuation, like the “замок” example. Can you think of a Russian word that is written in the same way but can be accented in **three** different ways and have **three** different meanings?

Comment: look in "СЛОВАРЬ ОМОГРАФОВ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА" Ю.Н. Гребенева

Comment: I don't have it, and I am very far away from any Russian library. If you know an electronic version, it would be nice if you could add it to our [resources question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)

Comment: Wikipedia has an [article](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84) about different types of homographs with many examples (though there are no examples that answer your question).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В Гугле по вполне очевидному запросу «тройные омографы» находится по меньшей мере [один весьма продуктивный трэд](http://miklukho-maklay.livejournal.com/100196.html) в ЖЖ. Я позволю себе перечислить приведенные там варианты:

- пе́репела (р. п. от *перепел*) — перепе́ла (пр. вр. III л. ж. р. от *перепеть*) — перепела́ (мн. ч. от *перепел*)
- ве́ртела (р. п. от *вертел*) — верте́ла (пр. вр. III л. ж. р. от *вертеть*) — вертела́¹ (мн. ч. от *вертел*)
- óкруга (р. п. от *округ*) — окрýга — округá (мн. ч. от *округ*)
- во́рота (р. п. от *во́рот*) — воро́та — ворота́²
- го́лубя (р. п. от *голубь*) — голу́бя (деепр. от *голу́бить*) — голубя́ (деепр. от *голуби́ть*³)

¹) Да, это нормативная форма множественного числа. Нет, не *ве́ртелы*. См. ГСРЯ.
²) *Пришла беда — отворяй ворота́.* Отличное тут от слова *воро́та* значение или нет — решайте сами.
³) *Голуби́ть* — красить голубым.

Comment: Great answer, especially p. 4. Decent stressing software should account for idioms too.

Comment: About вертела/вертелы... For some words, it's not quite clear where Zaliznyak took the recommendations from. He does list the dictionaries he used - and perhaps he just rewrote this from some older dictionary and never changed accordingly. Note that Kuznetsov's dictionary also suggests the prepositional singular "на вертелЕ" instead of "на вЕртеле"  so this word is probably undergoing the change to the a stress paradigm. Note there is another "вертел" where "вертелы" is acceptable: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/вертел#.D0.B2.D0.B5.CC.81.D1.80.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB_II

Comment: @Viridianus, я полагаю, что из собственного языка :-).  Вы думаете, что за полвека у слова «вертел» сдвинулась парадигма склонения с *-а́* во мн. ч. на *-ы*?  Может быть, конечно, но мне казалось, что в целом по языку сдвиг идет в обратную сторону: с *-ы* на *-а́*.  А что до ссылки на Викисловарь, то там два значения слова «вертел», и что у них разные парадигмы склонения, то вполне естественно: ср. напр. *про́пуски* / *пропуска́*.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Of course the usual movement is towards -а - but only for certain types of words where "вертел" probably does NOT belong.

Answer (score 13):

- *во́роны* - "ravens"
- *воро́ны* - "crows"
- *вороны́* - "black" (*эти кони саврасы, а те - вороны́*)

Comment: the third word is in different from, it's short adjective, while the first two are nouns

Comment: @Aksakal: so what?

Comment: I think this is a great answer, I just want to wait for some more examples from other people.