# What are the words, where stresses are important?

Tags: resources, ударение

There are some confusing words in russian, because they can be stressed differently and mean different things. I know some, like: "замки", "стрелки", "белки", "кружки". Is there a website [or any other resource] where such words are collected?

Comment: `ПисАть` - `to write`, `пИсать` - `to piss`. But I don't know is there the full list and where to find it.

Comment: A question about homographs (not about a website though): http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/4232/551

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that the answer is so much more complex than the topic starter may have thought is not good enough a reason for putting the question on hold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such words are called **омографы**. They have the same written form but are pronounced differently. There's also a larger group called **омонимы** which have the same written form and pronunciation (коса, for example). And there exists a special kind of dictionaries – "**Словарь омонимов русского языка**". I saw such a dictionary by **Ахманова**, it has a special part called Омографы, where you will find such words, translations into several languages,stresses, meanings etc.There's also a good introduction explaining the usage and forms.

Comment: Is there an online source or website, which has a list of homographs?

Comment: Yes, I saw this very dictionary online.  And there can be others. I will look for them.

Comment: Please post the URL, when you feel ready. Thank you!

Comment: http://accentonline.ru/homograph.html

Comment: https://publ.lib.ru›Archives›Archives/a›…/_Ahmanova_O.S..html

Comment: Here's the book available for downloading: http://padabum.net/d.php?id=49852

Answer (score 1):

This paper may be of particular interest:

https://repozytorium.amu.edu.pl/bitstream/10593/6650/1/077-082.pdf

According to it, there are thousands of Russian homographs.

And this book apparently addresses the phenomenon in detail. I do not know if it is available in an electronic form but hopefully may be purchased on line.

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=6.53