# Russian rhymes dictionary/materials

Tags: словарь

I would like to ask if there exists any **online** or **downloadable** descent dictionary of rhymes. I would prefer it to be structured and readable, so that I could eventually parse it. It is very important that it should not be a ready-to-use app like [rifmovnik.ru](http://rifmovnik.ru/docs.htm)

If there is no available free resource, then I would definitely ask you if it is legal to build my own dictionary based on extracts from internet libraries. I think this could be problematic because of the copyright.

Comment: [A possible duplicate](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)

Comment: @Olga, I agree it could be a duplicate. However, on the resource page I don't see any rhyme dictionaries mentioned (nor in the list provided). And I just need them urgently.

Comment: Поиск словаря окончаний дает [много ресурсов](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&oq=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5313j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Не все слова с одинаковыми окончаниями рифмуются. И наоборот - иногда рифмуются слова с абсолютно разными окончаниями (или вообще рифмуется слово с целым словосочетанием).

Comment: И потом, я уже все эти ресурсы просмотрела. Мне нужен именно словарь, а не поиск рифм по заданному слову.

Comment: AFAIK there is plenty of dictionaries for different spellchecker that are more or less free (GPL, MPL and other similar licenses).

Comment: Spellcheck? I was talking about rhymes...

Comment: I cautiously disagree that it's a duplicate - at least until some rhyme-specific info is added to the "resources" question.

Comment: Can't understand why mentioned [рифмовник](http://rifmovnik.ru/find) doesn't fit. Online descent rhyme finder, [one of many](http://google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D1%83).

Comment: @AndreyRegentov, I need a **dictionary** to write a parsing program and later generate random rhymes. I don't need a ready program to use. Please read the question carefully. I have mentioned why I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following links on downloadable rhyme dictionaries? (I think it is possible to extract database from such programs; or may be it is possible to use open API of their DLLs)

- http://softwarefor.ru/rhymes.html
- http://www.uchiyaziki.ru/index.php/slovar-rifm
- http://www.softportal.com/software-1530-rhymes.html

As I understand, you don't need online rhyme dictionaries. But I found and checked small list of working services, so decided to put it here:

- http://www.stihi.ru/assist/
- http://rifmakslovu.ru/online-generator-rifm
- http://rifmovnik.ru/find.htm

(I think it is good idea to try to ask owners of these web-services to send you their rhyme database)

Comment: OK, thanks! So the idea is that I need to somehow extract the databases. Thank you!

Comment: Oh noooo… Licence agreements. I am not allowed to decompile or disassembly the programs, nor to extract the database. Thus, the idea failed. But thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Sorry. I hope someone of owners of that sites will send you the database.