# Been learning Russian for 10 years, still can't understand my wife when she talks with her friends, what to do?

Tags: обучение

I really want to become fluent in Russian. And I've been trying for so many years.

With a risk that this question will be closed, I can't think of a better place to ask this.

My wife is of Russian origin (we don't speak Russian at home, I've been trying to ask her but she always gets back to my native language)

I've been over every single russian learning resource on the web. 99% of the "advanced russian" apps and audiobooks I've tried are already too easy for me and teach me nothing new. But I still can't get past this barrier, I'm trying to get my Russian to a level where I can

- Understand movies (e.g. Служебный роман)
- Understanding our friends / her when they talk in social settings (lot's of slang and coltural references)
- Understand the news
- Be able to read classic books (even classic childrens book use "high" words for me)

**What I tried:**

- I have a russian radio station on whenever I can, I can most of the time understand what the topic is, and if I try I can figure out individual words, but they talk so fast that I can't get it all connected (still not past the "translating it word by word" phase)
- Using Memrize to get the top 5,000 Russian words. I'm so far flashing through it (got to 500) and haven't found a single word I don't know. But I'm sure I'll get to new words soon.
- I tried to ask my wife to speak Russian to me, the kids will also benefit (they don't speak Russian!) but it's too hard, she always forgets and goes back to my native language (or English).

**What I'm looking for:**

- For my car - something like Memrize but with audio, just saying a word and it's translation. There are probably many of these, but I can't find the one that fits my vocabulary level. Most of the ones I tried simply repeat the same old "how to get from the bus to the train station and get a hotel room" vocabulary that is not really helping me move to the next level.
- How I wish there was a website for russian learning where they record real people speak and then play it slowly and explain word by word.
- Same for movies - I wonder if there is some program that takes a famous Russian movie and plays it slowly and explains all words that are not "common" (e.g. not top 1000).

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate or violating the FAQ, but I really can't think of a more relevant place to ask that question (I'm a programmer, so on my drive to work I asked myself, why isn't there a "stackoverflow" for Russian learning?and then I realized, that it might already exist, so happy it does, please don't close me as off topic / non constructive, you are my only hope)

**Bottom line**

I've tried almost everything and I can't get to the "advanced" level in Russian for the past 10 years or so. What are some recommended action items to move to the next level? (Except moving to Russia for a few years, I asked my wife and she refuses at the moment, although I would love to personally)

Comment: Sounds a lot like me and Arabic — minus the wife, but I worked at an Arabic-language radio station for three years and it didn't do the trick for me. I suppose nothing will really work until you get to actively use the language in a real-life setting. Preferably one where you *have* to use it. Otherwise, the brain just doesn't seem to treat the information as worthy of retaining.

Comment: @NikolayErshov anecdotally I've been trying to learn Arabic too! La bakdar Afham :) I think Arabic is even harder by the way. Need to learn two languages (spoken and written). Can't even say I got the spoken part to a basic level. Good luck!

Comment: 1 word, youtube

Comment: http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/6750/5560

Comment: I've been watching the Simpsons for more than 5 years to get all the cultural references when I speak English(English is not my native language). Perhaps, you could download a Russian TV or radio show, listen to one episode over and over and get the script and analyse it. That is what I do whenever I learn a new language. Get the real spoken language from the media and repeat.

Comment: I'm responsible for the answer that qy directed you to and I just added some new content to it on a really good podcast. I was in your shoes less than a year ago and now I understand everything. In fact, I'm needing to work on making my tongue catch up with my ears at this point ;)

Comment: I find the best way to get someone to talk in a specific language is to use that language - i.e. talk to your wife with what Russian you do know, and don't worry if she response in English/your native language - make your reply be in Russian (don't mention anything about her switching to whatever), and keep the conversation going.

Comment: A new wife, perhaps?

Comment: If you're truly desperate, move to Russia?

Comment: Learn Yiddish, both of you :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin this is an off-topic question that has some historical significance and thus can not be deleted. It can not be treated as a question that can have a single answer though.

Comment: @NickVolynkin comments are not always constructive, I can provide thousands  of examples of non-constructive comments at stack that  were intended to be funny but are not that funny actually (just like these two). Whenever you fundamentally don't agree with moderator - and believe that he/she's acting blatantly wrong, feel free to raise a question at russian meta

Comment: @shabunc what's really wrong and destructive here is that you're a mod and your declining my flags is imperative and can result in myself having a flag ban.

Comment: Consider https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/tips-for-learning-japanese-zack-davisson/ - that is not about Russian, but the issue at hand the same: becoming fluent in real spoken language. And of 5 advices two (#2 and #5) are directly telling: without real conversation with living people it is just not attainable. So if your wife shuns her Russian, then perhaps you'd try to find some Russina-language local community, or invite some Russian emigrant to your work vacant places, etc.

Comment: Your question title made me smile. Don't worry -- Russian is impossible, but keep at it, and you may have the honor to understand your wife before you die. And, the suggestion of @ddbug is not entirely ridiculous.

Comment: Or, watch this video...   https://youtu.be/sM6yJSuGZK8

Answer (score 12):

***we don't speak Russian at home

Вот и объяснение вашего языкового барьера. Сайты и аудио вам не помогут, нужна интенсивная практика с носителями языка.

Comment: Это короткий ответ по сути вопроса. Без воды и с конкретным советом.. :)

Comment: У меня опыт преподавания 13 лет. Самая частая ошибка - это попытка изучать speaking, занимаясь listening или reading. Конкретный скилл изучается и тренируется, когда вы именно им и занимаетесь.

Comment: Добавив последний комментарий в свой ответ вы его радикально улучшите! (Вы всегда можете редактировать свои посты).

Comment: @Artemix Спасибо. Скажите, пожалуйста, а вы модератор? Я просто тут столкнулся с конфликтной ситуацией и не знаю, у кого спросить совета. Описал ее здесь - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260415/how-do-i-solve-conflict-situation-here

Comment: В зависимости от уровня репутации пользователям даются права на разные коллективные модерационные действия, но полноправных модераторов у нас трое: http://russian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @SergZ. Ставьте флаги на сообщения с угрозами и переходом на личности.

Answer (score 11):

I will answer in Russian because it seems that you know it well enough. I've translated some phrases which seem the most difficult to me. If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

> My wife is of Russian origin (we don't speak Russian at home, I've been trying to ask her but she always gets back to my native language)

У вас рядом есть носитель языка (native speaker). Простое общение — это лучший способ учить язык, по крайней мере улучшать навыки устной речи. Почему она предпочитает говорить по-английски? Возможно, это просто удобно, а особого смысла говорить по-русски нет. Попробуйте поговорить об этом с такой позиции (in the following manner/way) : вы хотите изучать русский и вам нужна ее помощь. Вы можете договориться о том, чтобы говорить по-русски пару часов в день или в какие-то определенные дни. Попробуйте поставить общую задачу и вместе ее выполнять.

Еще один ресурс - фильмы с субтитрами (*на русском языке*, просто чтобы лучше понимать речь). Если вы не поймете какие-то слова - ничего страшного (not a trouble), попробуйте понять по контексту. Я сам два года назад решил, что хочу совершенствовать понимание английского на слух. Абсолютно все фильмы, которые я просмотрел за эти два года, были на английском. Поначалу я использовал английские субтитры, но совсем недавно заметил, что они мне уже не нужны.

Аудиокниги прекрасны тем, что их (обычно) читают профессиональные дикторы. У них правильное произношение (correct pronunciation) и они никуда не спешат, в отличие от радиоведущих (radio DJs). Снова из личного опыта: прослушал первую книгу о Гарри Поттере в исполнении Стивена Фрая, у которого идеальный британский акцент. Кстати, можете спросить у жены о ее любимых произведениях русской литературы и послушать их.

То, что вы упорно идете к своей цели уже 10 лет, вызывает уважение. Продолжайте в том же духе, успех придёт.

Comment: Great tips! I understood 80% of the words :) I think watching movies with English subtitles is a great idea. We are going to watch formula lubvi today!

Comment: @EranMedan  A great movie, if it's what I think of. I'd recommend `Кин-дза-дза`, `Иван Васильевич меняет профессию`, and other Soviet-epoch comedies. Don't watch modern Russian movies, they're... well, not as good as they could be.

Comment: Notice that I meant watching with Russian subtitles! No translation, just helping you catch the words.

Comment: I would not recommend Кин-дза-дза. It uses a lot of invented words, also some words of Georgian origin. Not a best choice to learn Russian vocabulary.

Comment: @Anixx that is true. But education should be joyful. That was my intent.

Comment: `Кин-дза-дза` can be an indicator - if you can understand it as native speakers and discuss with them, then your Russian is really good.

Comment: From modern Russian movies I could recommend a couple of TV series like https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B and https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%8F_%28%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%29

Comment: @UVV those are cheap sitcoms and not movies )

Comment: @Nick Volynkin I know, but they are still funny and have a lot of useful vocabulary at the same time. They would be more useful nowadays than `Кин-дза-дза`, which I must admit I didn't watch :)

Comment: `Кин-дза-дза` is good, but it's full of non existent words, I'd agree with UVV's advice.

Comment: @EugenePetrov so are the Star Wars. Midichlorians and other stuff.

Answer (score 6):

I feel I can relate to where you come from a little.
I am a programmer who has a wife who came from a foreign country and speaks a foreign language. She is from the U.S. and we speak English at home.
Soon we will have our first born and the common tongue will be English. Plus, I will teach him some Korean (my native language) so he can talk to his grandpa.

I have been watching a lot of TV shows from English speaking countires (mostly U.K. and U.S.) to get all the cultural references.

The Simpsons(U.S.) and My Family (U.K.) did a good job.

Get some DVDs of famous Russian TV shows and watch it over and over.
They will probably have Russian subtitles too for the disabled.

Also, go to a broadcast station website.
When I was learning, I went to BBC.
They usually have news articles and the video or audio streaming that you can watch or listen to. That way you can listen and have the scripts for you to analyse.

I used to go to vesti.ru but these days I can't make some time for it.

I am currently reading the Alchemist by Paulo Coelho in Russian.
I have read this book 5 times in English.
Repetetion is my friend.
Find your favourite books in Russian and read them.
If books like these (for adults) are too difficult, read childrens books too.

If you do not understand something, **study again until you understand**.

I could not find any other way than **repeat until you get it**.

Answer (score 5):

Words, Words, and more words—in my experience I needed to know 7–8,000 words before things became much easier. Maybe this isn't a problem for you, sorry :), but I think a lot of people can't understand a language simply because they don't know enough words. That doesn't mean one should just learn words—you have to listen and read too—but it's impossible to understand something if you're lacking the vocabulary.

If Vocabulary is not a problem, than I would suggest listening to things that are just a little above your level—start with kids shows, then move up; don't start with movies or difficult books. I started with shows for 5 year olds then 12 then 15 then etc etc—it's way more motivating than starting with the hardest materials.

Good luck with everything :)

PS—Route memorization and repetition the old fashioned way works just as well as the fancy programs in my opinion)))

Comment: I think this is my problem. Working on memrise and anki to fix that!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the main problem is the lack of self-confidence. That's not really a problem if your wife is speaking English to you. Just answer her in Russian.

It's great that you can mostly understand the posts written in Russian but it would be much better if you asked your question in it.

How to make yourself to believe you can talk Russian well, well, it's a different story. Personally I found that "hardways" really help.

Do you want to be able to read classic books in Russian? Then start reading them. It's OK if you can't understand a word - more frequently you'd use a dictionary. Afraid of "high words"? Read poetry every day before the breakfast. Even if you'll never use these words in everyday life simply knowing them is the evidence you know Russian well.

In short, if you want to go forward then do move forward. You have everything for that.

Comment: Overall, it can be very difficult to get Russians to speak Russian, lol. They are kind of jerks about pushing their own interests in speaking English—this doesn't apply to his wife, obviously. I always find it amusing when someone responds to my Russian with English that's no better than my Russian. Even teachers will do this until you tell them to stop.

Comment: That's the hint: take any chance to practice. What seems more amusing to me is that people learning Russian do avoid talking Russian when they have such a possibility.

Comment: Old people are good language partners—they respect the exchange, lol, and Russians that don't speak English are obviously cool too.

Answer (score 2):

One more 'tip' from the one not in the situation of Russian learners, rather an English learner. Personal experience, as usual.

**Subtitles** help to understand words but they can draw away from oral *speech* recognition. It can be a torture to try to listen to dialogues and follow the subtitles for speech fragments I can’t make out. Once I started to read subtitles I can’t stop and get back to hear actual speaking. Even worse if it trains to hear through the written text.
Vocabulary is not your biggest problem, as I can see. But mostly you are in the abyss of **passive/written** language learning. (Aren’t you?) Logic says: strive to make it *active*; use your Russian whenever possible (don’t care how good it is — someone’s life depends on it?). First let is start 'running'.
One more thing: comprehending in a slow and/or word-by-word way can be a false strategy. Put it aside for cases when nothing else helps.
At last, I mention *my* double mistake: (1) trying to understand everything at once in oral speech (a gimme-all-’n-now mistake), (2) trying it hard with all my *intellectual* abilities when hearing — the system gets overloaded quickly. Certain things can be skipped to be keeping in touch with what is being spoken. (When you just start catching the speech.) Sometimes lazy, non-mind-struggling hearing can open the gates closed for conscious efforts. Though repeating the unhearable seem to be the principal way.

Well, you asked what to do, I sang mostly about what not to.
Sorry if too much of imperative here…

Comment: By comparison, I learn well from subtitles and find them unobtrusive.

Answer (score 2):

> If I try I can figure out individual words, but they talk so fast that
>   I can't get it all connected (still not past the "translating it word
>   by word" phase)

If a teacher didn’t tell you about the fact that there are 2 classes of languages, one take **a predominantly consonants approach** (*русский*), and at the other end is the vowels approach (*English*), that's the problem. *Русский, польский, болгарский, сербский...* these languages belong to the consonants approach.

I am sure **You cannot hear/understand up to 60% of the consonants spoken.**

---

Факты:
В русском (и современном греческом) гласных фонем всего 6. Согласных фонем 34. В русском гласные не различаются по долготе/краткости. Согласные -- главная сигнальная система.

Английский: 21 фонема гласных, 25 согласных. Гласные -- главная сигнальная система.

Вторая сигнальная система в русском это ударение. К примеру, поставим неверное ударение на последний открытый слог в слове `рыба`. Мы получим два почти не различимых на слух звуковых ряда:
[(confusing "как гриб́ы?" for "как рыб́ы?", and saying they are good when I clearly have no mushrooms on my plate)](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/how-can-i-improve-my-listening-comprehension/).

Здесь рекомендовали фильмы, не думаю, что фильмы это хорошее средство для тренировки на слух каждодневного разговорного русского. В фильмах разговорный язык — искусственный. Пишут сценарий, далее фильмы озвучивают по фразам, эти фразы начитывают с текста, и любую фразу произносят заново, если что-то не так. Даже если в фразы вставляют междометия, вводные, просторечные слова, это всё равно читается с текста. Это имитация разговорного.

Фильмы, действительно, помогут вам узнать, **как говорить правильно**.

Но это едва ли поможет вам тренировать на слух ежедневный русский.

Я предлагаю слушать радио. Попробуйте. Найдите знакомые фразы в тексте, и послушайте, **как они звучат в непринужденной речи**. Я потратил своё время, написал субтитры, чтобы дать почувствовать, как мы говорим.

podcast.govoritmoskva.ru/?p=911
«Подъём» 2015-07-06

Да, мы так говорим! :)

```
=0.30=  С.ДОРЕНКО: 9 часов 6 минут. Понедельник, 6 июля. 
=0.46=  Здравствуй, великий город! Здравствуйте все! 
        Даррррррррррррррррррррррр... радио "Говорит Москва".... 
        "Говорит Москва"! 
=1.11=  Эльвира Хасаншина -- ведущая этой программы. Здравствуйте,
        Эльвира (И Сергей Доренко. Доброе утро)
=1.15=  Чили - чемпионы Южной Америки, поздравляю
=1.18=  Чилийских слушателей, чилийкослушателей... не пониманию, 
=1.22=  'Тор', 'Тор' у вас опечатка 
=2.24=  Не каждый может иметь миллионы, но каждый может стремиться 
=1.27=  пишет 'Кличко и В'.
=1.28=  Были в субботу в Новосибирском зоопарке 
=1.31=  Там больше нет слонов и жирафов 
=1.33=  детям понравилось, а я расстроился 
=1.35=  Сообщает Денис Гудков, спасибо!
=1.37=  Пишите нам на Говорит-Москва-точка-ру,
=1.39=  Говорит-Москва-точка-ру, написать в эфир
=1.41=  а также на sms +7 925 8 8 8 8 9 4 и 8, 8 8 8 8 9 4 и 8
=1.50=  и лента в Твитере "Говорит МСК"
=1.53=  Представитель Макаревича опроверг информацию
=1.56=  о смерти певца
=1.58=  Представитель Макаревича опроверг информацию о смерти.
=2.02=  (и об этом он сказал нам) Да, он сообщил об этом
=2.05=   радиостанции "Говорит Москва"
=2.08=  Константин Петров нам пишет 
=2.09=  ссылаясь на нас же
=2.10=  а, так вот же, значит, вы уже знаете что
=2.14=  был взломан, вероятно, взломан
=2.15=  эээ... сайт, э фестиваля э, эт, Грушинского
=2.19=  (Грушинского) Грушинского фестиваля
=2.21=  взломан и на заглавной странице
=2.23=  провисело довольно долго сообщение о
=2.25=  том, что убит Макаревич
=2.27=  значит, представитель певца только что
=2.29=  врл... в интервью радиостанции "Говорит-Москва"
=2.31=  опроверг, опроверг это м... сообщение
=2.34=  вероятно, с... сайт грушинского фестиваля
=2.37=  был взломан, ну или кто-то пошутил [? с самолетом ?]
=2.41=  какой-то пьяный админ, что-то такое... 
=2.42=  и так далее. Понимаете, значит, 
=2.44=  ээ... скажите, пожалуйста,
=2.46=  Макара похоронил... нет, нет, именно грушинский фестиваль
=2.50=  ээ... похоронил Макара
=2.52=  вероятно, хакер.
=2.53=  Но теперь мы знаем, что...
=2.55=  и вообще говоря, это было похоже на... ..
=2.59=  на хакерскую выходку, несмотря на то, что они
=3.01=  и, в, они проникли на заглавную  страницу,
=3.05=  это было похоже, потому что
=3.08=  если бы это произошло в действительности,
=3.09=  то конечно, МВД бы рапортовало, 
=3.11=  и так далее, и так далее,
=3.12=  понимаешь, так что, так что... 
=3.13=  (да, и информационные агенства)
=3.14=  конечно-конечно-конечно, но ничего не было.
=3.16=  скажите пожалуйста, поступок Земфиры -- ЗНАЧИТ -- или нет?
=3.20=  Вот у меня вопрос. Простой. 
=3.22=  Вообще говоря, слова -- значат?
=3.24=  Дела  -- значат? Символы -- значат?
=3.26=  (Значат.) Значат? (Конечно.) 
=3.28=  (Они потому наверное, и символы)
=3.30=  Вообще, всё значат. Всё -- значат.
=3.34=  (Да) ну правда...
=3.35=  (я считаю, что да)
=3.37=  Давайте, давайте проголосуем.
=3.38=  Скажите пожалуйста, поступок Земфиры,
=3.39=  я понимаю, что это пятничное, но в субботу, как вы знаете,
=3.41=  она взорвала нам мозг, и
=3.43=  э, я для себя думал,
=3.45=  поступок Земфиры -- значит?
=3.48=  вообще говоря,
=3.50=  следует ли, поступку Земфиры
=3.51=  с флагом Украины придавать значение?
=3.54=  Да -- 134 21 35
=3.57=  Нет -- 134 21 36
=3.59=  следует ли поступку Земфиры
```

podcast.govoritmoskva.ru/?p=905
«Подъём» 2015-07-03

```
=0.30=  С.ДОРЕНКО: 9 часов 6 минут. Пятница, 3 июля. 
=0.45=  Здравствуй, великий город! Здравствуйте все! 
        Даррррррррррррррррррррррр... радио "Говорит Москва".... 
        "Говорит Москва"! 
=1.11=  Анастасия Оношко -- ведущая этой программы. (И Сергей 
        Доренко. Доброе утро, Сергей.) Здравствуйте, Анастасия. 
        Доброе утро. 
=1.15=  Говорит 'ДерзкийЮрец'... Доброе утро, говорит 96-ой   
=1.20=  А... это Степан 
=1.21=  а я люблю 'Шнура' придаёт... признаётся 
=2.24=  Алексей 
=1.25=  так говорит 'МСК' в твитере.  
=1.26=  а... м... ещё... 
=1.27=  хорошее ли у вас настроение спрашивает 'дабл ю вай джей' 
=1.31=  Да! всегда хорошее! Всг... конечно... 
=1.34=  всегда хорошее... 
=1.35=  Что написано у вас на майке? 
=1.36=  На моей майке написано, что я мусор. 
=1.38=  (Да) прочитай (под... под прикрытием полиции, наппп...)
=1.40=  написано, что я мусор под прикрытием.  
=1.42=  Для резиденции свердловского губернатора
=1.45=  заказали шторы за 700 тысяч рублей
=1.47=  (там кабинет такой) 
=1.48=  (на два с половиной метра) ну видите, он видимо 
=1.49=  большой очень 
=1.51=  активисты движения 'За Честные Закупки' обнаружили 
=1.52=  на сайте госзакупок заказ на шторы 
=1.55=  для резиденции губернатора 
=1.57=  Свердловской области. Общая сумма которого 
=1.59=  составила 700 тысяч рублей 
=2.01=  согласно документации к аукциону
=2.03=  шторы в кабинет руководителя размером 
=2.04=  три на два с половиной метра 
=2.06=  ах, подожди-ка, (я говорю) ... 
=2.07=  мамочка! (так мы проводим секвестор бюджета) 
=2.08=  так это всего... 
=2.09=  так это всего одни шторы, это на одно окно! 
=2.13=  это на одно окно, одно! 
=2.15=  (я думаю, это площадь кабинета) 
=2.16=   да нет же, три на два с половиной метра 
=2.19=  всего 
=2.20=  (площадь шторы) шторы, 
=2.21=  и за них 700 тысяч рублей. Они должны быть
=2.23=  изготовлены из 100% полиэстера 
=2.26=  с бархатными портьерами 
=2.28=  и с карнизом из декоративного багета
=2.31=  ах, как это прелестно! (да) закуплено на 700 тысяч рублей (да) 
=2.35=  (да) мда 
=2.36=  а, подожди, ээээ... 
=2.37=  на одно окно 136... 
=2.38=  не понимаю, не понимаю,  
=2.41=  да, но это историческое здание 
=2.42=  и это исторические шторы 
=2.44=  ты подумай об этом сейчас 
=2.46=  когда ты говоришь а просвещении, (да) 
=2.48=  не э, э... (о сокращении количества) а ты говоришь 
=2.50=  о просвещении, 
=2.51=  о музеях, 
=2.52=  ведь ты радеешь за просвещение (да)
=2.54=  за музеи, (да) 
=2.56=  а когда здание губернатора... 
=2.57=  это в Свердловской области? (в Свердловской области) 
=2.58=  я был у него, я был у Росселя
=3.00=  еще в гостях, ты помнишь эту историю? Я тебе
=3.02=  рассказывал, когда Газманов... 
=3.03=  (что-то такое...) Газманова 
=3.04=  Газманова не пустили (рассказывали) Газманова не 
=3.05=  пустили завтракать в гостинице 
=3.06=  из-за того что там ел я 
=3.08=  (нет) я тебе рассказывал, 
=3.10=  (я уже забыла, расскажите ещё раз, пожалуйста) 
=3.12=  я был в гостях у Росселя 
=3.14=  у него был какой то юбилей, 
=3.15=  может, может быть, может быть сто лет, 
=3.17=  или сто пятьдесят ему было лет... 
=3.19=  ээ, и, в этот момент, в этот момент 
=3.21=  меня поселили в гостинице 
=3.23=  и, когда я явился к завтраку (да) 
=3.26=  ээ, то, 
=3.27=   мм, значит, 
=3.28=  вдруг я услышал, когда за спиною за моей,  
=3.31=  когда я съедал салатик, 
=3.32=  из помидорчиков, 
=3.33=  за спиною за моей, я услышал скандал (возник) 
=3.36=  мне стало теперь ясно, да, как она возня, скандал, пфф, 
=3.40=  и, ээ, ээ, злобное шипение: 'нет нельзя! нет нельзя!', 
=3.43=  'не велено пускать', 
=3.44=  ии, наконец, 
=3.45=  ээ, когда я 
=3.47=  спросил, спросил официанта: 
=3.48=  'скажите пожалуйста, 
=3.49=  что за глупая возня, какая-то, которая мне портит аппетит?'
=3.53=  Они сказали: ээ
=3.55=  Это Газманов, певец Газманов, рвётся 
=3.57=  позавтракать. Я сказал: 
=3.59=  'Какая грязь!' 
=4.00=  А что, а почему, он не такой же? 
=4.02=  (а утренний голод, он такой) Я тебе хочу сказать, 
         нет, я сказал: 
=4.04=  "хорошо, а почему? 
=4.05=  А что случилось? 
=4.07=  А что, вот же столы, столы, столы..." 
=4.08=  там был большой зал (да, да) 
=4.10=  они сказали: 
=4.11=  'дело в том, что 
=4.12=  принято решение, что пока вы не 
=4.14=  позавтракали, чтобы не нарушать ваш покой, 
=4.15=  чтобы не нарушать ваш покой, 
=4.17=  эээ... (они думали, что Газманов бросится у вас брать...) 
=4.18=  никого не пускать, 
=4.20=  никого не... они думали что 
=4.22=  (бросится у Вас брать интервью) 
=4.23=  нет, что 
=4.24=  Газманов ворвётся в, в зал завтрака, с криком: 
=4.27=  'Москва!!! Гремят колокола!!!' (понятно) что-нибудь такое...
=4.29=  а я тут ку[шать] изволил...    
=4.31=  (эскадрон моих мыслей шальных)
=4.34=  абсолютно верно...
=4.36=  я подошел лично к дверце, к этой, которая пускала в зал
=4.39=  (Вы открыли, Вы впустили его?) 
=4.40=  я сказал администратору, этой пылкой женщине, лет 45-ти 
=4.44=  (как к тореодору, впускают быка)
=4.45=  я сказал, я оказал: "прошу вас, пожалуйста" 
=4.48=  я считаю это неправильным 
=4.51=  я считаю это неправильно, [? помиловались ?] 
=4.53=  что за элитарность? 
=4.54=  я готов... 
=4.56=  я готов с этим пая... ну я готов... (тем более это Газманов...)
```

Comment: Ну и чушь они там мелют на этом радио. :) Зачем это слушать не только иностранцу но вообще кому-либо?

Comment: @NickVolynkin , а что Вы хотели от ежедневной полуторачасовой программы? :) А Вы когда-н. пробовали записать субтитрами болтовню двух женщин по телефону? Вот то-то же. Я постарался показать на этих примерах **произношение связанных слов, когда фонемы примыкают друг к другу.** Сайти типа *Forvo*, где искусственно-дикторски проговоривают отдельные слова, это зло, в смысле вопроса OP. Зато в этих примерах — точно то, что услышите в автобусе, в баре, на пляже, в компании и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite tell from your question - have you taken a Russian course with a real teacher, or worked from a good book (rather than gathering internet resources)?

It's great that you've worked on vocabulary, but do you have a solid understanding of the structure of the language - meaning case endings, aspect, motion verbs, etc.?

After studying Russian for many years, and teaching it for over 14 years, I've observed that good courses scaffold the language - gradually introducing new structures - and make you practice those before moving on to the next, let alone advanced tasks like understanding authentic speech in a film. Since you're not a 2-year old living in Russia I'm afraid you won't be able to just absorb it the way native speakers do.

I'd urge you to work your way through Nicholas Brown's 'New Penguin Russian Course' (about $15 on Amazon), perhaps with an online tutor who has experience teaching foreign learners; there are also several good Youtube channels that focus on Russian grammar (full disclosure: I have one, don't want to spam you here though). If you know the material in Brown's book (yes, all of it!) already, try to find an online tutor who can assess your level and suggest more advanced learning materials.

For radio: at [this page](http://echo.msk.ru/top/programs.html) on Эхо Москвы you can mouse over a program & click читать for a transcript. Super handy.

For film: look for Мосфильм on Youtube, where they have a few [classic movies with *Russian* subtitles](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4dWJMOQ_a1TPLZbU-K3ic_HODgNTppT9); or buy DVDs of good films with Russian subtitles - that can be a great bridge as you work your way up to managing authentic materials.

Успеха!

Answer (score 0):

Увы, кино, телепередачи и даже живая речь очень слабо насыщены фразеологизмами. Фразеологизмы (idioms) составляют главную трудность в понимании языка.

Мне кажется, что лучше изучать идиомы в их концентрированном виде.

Найдите бесплатную компьютерную программу "РазгРусс" (разговорный русский). В ней более тысячи труднопонимаемых разговорных фраз, как наговоренных дикторами, так и взятых из песен, радиопередач, фильмов, телешоу. Тренинг заключается в выборе подходящего толкования фразы из предлагаемого списка. Сами фразы можно либо просто читать, либо читать и слушать, либо только слушать.
Наверное, такая программа понравится и Вашей жене.

Answer (score 0):

There's something I've stumbled upon recently -- music by Аквариум and Борис Гребенщиков, which I listen to through Amazon Prime. [This](http://www.planetaquarium.com/discography/songs.html) is their website with lyrics to the songs.  I've learned several of the songs, and lots of vocabulary and usage along with it, such as Поезд в Огне.  Amazon also has the spoken Russian New Testament with dramatization.  Also, there's music by Владимир Высоцкий such as Москва Одесса. You could also pick up works by some famous authors such as Солженицын ([Один день Ивана Денисовича](http://www.lib.ru/PROZA/SOLZHENICYN/ivandenisych.txt)).  Anyway, just keep pounding on it.  Improvement will come gradually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with books. I consider it the easiest thing to learn in the "read < write < listen < speak" hierarchy.

> even classic childrens book use "high" words for me

So, you've found your first reproducible problem. Now go debug it. Read the books online an install some translator extension (e.g. Yandex Translate https://element.yandex.ru/translate) so that you can get instant translation for any unknown word.