# where can I learn everyday Russian for free?

Tags: other-languages

I want to improve my Russian language skills (esp. speaking). Could you please post any useful online sources (for example: language chats, poscasts, videos..)

Comment: I think it's possible a [**duplicate**](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/8967/5288 "Been learning russian for 10 years, still can't understand my wife when she talks with her friends, what to do?")