# Аналог словаря Макмилана для изучающих русский язык

Tags: узус, resources, словарь

Для изучающих английский язык существует отличный ресурс -- словарь [Макмилана](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/). В нем приводится куча разной лексики с поясниями, примерами употребления и т.д.

Кто-нибудь знает хороший аналог, но для изучения русского языка?

Comment: Не думаю, что русский язык можно всерьез учить с одним словарем: как минимум, нужен толковый и грамматический.

Comment: Толковые словари русского языка  имеют такую  же структуру. На начальном этапе обычно пользуются двуязычными словарями. А на вкус и цвет...

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: [Resources for learning Russian](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)

Answer (score 2):

Я использую тот интернет-ресурс: http://translate.academic.ru
В нем найдешь и толкованя и переводы.
К сожалению иногда рекламные баннеры мешают.

Answer (score 0):

It's always help: http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?&l1=1&l2=2&CL=1&a=0

For rus->eng and for eng->rus

Answer (score -4):

Я нашел исключительно мощная и полезная функция "Переводчик", который находится на главной странице российского интернет-браузер "Yandex.ru". Я использую этот браузер прямо сейчас, чтобы ответить на Ваш вопрос, введя текст в поле ввода на английском языке, а затем "выделение, копирование и вставка" на русский язык перевод в поле "stackexchange.com" ответа на ответ Вам. Попробуйте!

Comment: One cannot learn the language by using a tool that does the work for him. Especially because automatic translations are far from being good. You cannot trust them in terms of usage examples, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment re machine translations.  I believe that such tools are only as good as the hands and head of those who use them.  I regularly use Яндекс for learning Russian and Bulgarian grammar, vocabulary, and spelling.  I also use it intermittently as an aid for some of the other languages I have learned and understand -- German, Spanish, Italian, and French.

Comment: Artemix: Here is a Russian-style analogy in response to your off-topic negative vote:  Двое мужчин рыть канавы. Один человек роет канавы с киркой и лопатой. Второй человек роет канавы с угробив машину он арендовал сад бизнес предложения. Конечный результат для двух мужчин точно так же: в конце дня они оба копали рвы!

Comment: "угробив машину он арендовал сад бизнес предложения" - looks like a sequence of random words (but I guess it was an automatic translation of something).

Comment: Artemix:  Be careful.  As a professional computer programmer and student of the Russian language you certainly do know that your comment fragment "-- looks like a sequence of random words (but I guess it was an automatic translation of something)." is intentionally misleading as well as being intentionally deprecating.  Your statement is not only inaccurate, but it is also a clear violation of StackExchange Community Standards.  Delete your statement, or be forewarned of the consequences to your Reputation points if you do not do so.

Comment: Artemix: А тепер українська мова (який я знаю, що ви знаєте, набагато краще, ніж ви робите на англійській і російській мовах), я попереджав, Troll, ваша поведінка по відношенню до мене неприйнятно і порушує Закони спільноти для будь-якого з SO сайтів / SE і їх форумах.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment upset you, but automatic translation really made a mess from your joke. As a professional programmer I can tell you that currently automatic tools are not good for getting quality results. If you think my comments are violating anything - you can flag my comments for moderator attention.

Comment: And I have done so.