# Can't understand the Genitive Case in Russian

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, падежи, прилагательные

I can`t exactly wrap my head about the “-ого” ending in a word for example “русского”. When do we add it? And how is it used?

Comment: Check your grammar book or any other general source. This question as it is now is too broad.

Comment: I did but I don't get it

Comment: And I don't have a book I study alone

Comment: @Groude `I don't have a book` Look at [this question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian). Also keep in mind that "кого" belongs to two cases: Genitive and Accusative.